Flutter Sliver heaader pinned at top and bottom
I am working on a Flutter project and want to implement a CustomScrollView with pinned headers. Specifically, I would like each header to stick to the top of the screen only once it has been fully scrolled past. Until then, it should remain at the bottom of the section it belongs to.
Is this behavior possible in Flutter? If so, what would be the best way to achieve it?
In the following screenshot, we are currently scrolling through the "Header 2" section, and I would like "Header 3" and "Header 4" to be pinned at the bottom.

